# how to change custom option contents color in magento

Tags: magento-1.8

Hi im johnny im the new guy to magento , recently i face a small issues about custom options radio button and checkbox display contents color white, as the contents color is white , in the front end i can't see any texts in the radio button select area. does anyone have idea to fix it? i tried to use the google chrome to locate it to change the contents color. but when i refresh the web page, the color change back. i hope somebody can help .thanks
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After you change the color in Chrome browser, it is required to copy the strings you've added to a main .css file. Otherwise, those changes will expire.

Comment: Hi Evgen thank you for you reply,  i use the Chrome to locate currently contents .Css and i changed the contents color to black, and it appeared black, but when i refresh the Web page it is change back to white,  can you tell me how to locate to the main.css file, how to change the strings. i couldn't find it.  this is really urgent

Comment: Use Chrome to find the style class that is considered with the content of custom options. There should be an attribute set and you will see it in the browser. The white color code is #ffffff(or #fff). Change the HEX to the one you need and do the following. Open the main CSS file and find the style class that you've just edited. Change the color in it and save the changes. Then refresh the page and check the color. Also, consider using a ready-to-install plugin like this https://store.orange35.com/image-constructor-for-custom-options-for-magento